# Text aligned with the figure tag

Tags: floats, aligned, captionof

How can I add a text aligned with the figure tag, similar to a footnote (without numbering)?. What I have tried to do, without any success, is something like what is shown in red, in the figure below
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{ Image }
\end{center}

\lipsum[2-2]

\end{document}
```

additional image

[image]

Comment: Can you also add a sample image of what things would look like with a wider (and/or multiline) caption?

Comment: Ok. I have already added an additional image with one of the applications in which the code could be used.

Comment: What if the caption is multiline? Are all your images centred? Off-topic: are you sure this is a good idea?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the label is multi-line, what matters is quick access to additional relevant information at a glance, without having to scroll to a footnote or a text search. The idea is to keep the focus on relevant information without getting scattered. And yes, all images are centered

Comment: When the caption is centered, one would need to know the width to match a centered box (\makebox or \parbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that the `singlelinecheck` automatically computes the width of the caption.  However, this is performed in many different locations depending on the options.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption,lipsum}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[3][\empty]{% #1=short caption (optionsl), #2=caption, #3=text
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \caption[#1]{#2}%
  \else
    \caption[#1]{#2}
  \fi
  \sbox0{\figurename~\thefigure:}% compute width of line
  \sbox1{\usebox0 #2}% compute width of centered text
  \ifdim\wd1>\linewidth \wd1=\linewidth \fi% perform single line check
  \parbox{\wd1}{\raggedright\footnotesize
  \leavevmode\rlap{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\rule{\wd0}{0.5pt}}}%
  #3}\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{figure}[ht]% to avoid large blank spaces
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\mycaption{Some sort of image}{Source: Image black book}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, nice.  Could we align the text with "Figure"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I coulld put the text into one line using `\makebox`.

Comment: If the text in  "Figure 1: .....Image ...." tag increases, "Source:...." remains centered and does not scroll with the "Figure" tag.

Comment: You have to use the same text in `\sbox1` as in the caption.  One could do both with one command.

Comment: Ok, I saw it. Thank you!